# selenium doesn't find any element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I can't interfere with any element on this site. Could you help ? Thank you very much for your answers in advance.

https://pttws.ptt.gov.tr/info_web/info_kayit.jsp

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  
driver.get("https://pttws.ptt.gov.tr/info_web/info_kayit.jsp")
inputs = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "input")

for input_element in inputs:
    print(input_element.get_attribute("id"))
```

++

```
devTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52080/devtools/browser/196a44c6-8117-4520-bce9-a02c51c2a35f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r00t\Downloads\test_ptt.py", line 16, in <module>
    inputs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "input")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 861, in find_elements
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENTS, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"] or []
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It seems like you expect to find ALL the `<input>` elements, not just one.  So you should use `find_elements()` (see the S on the end?), not `find_element()`.

Comment: Can you share the error on your console?

Comment: _interfere with any element on this site_: Which specific `<input>`element are you looking to invoke click?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code that you've provided, but the webpage is taking too long to load, it is timing out, causing the error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

inputs = bs(requests.get("https://pttws.ptt.gov.tr/info_web/info_kayit.jsp").text, 'html.parser').find_all('input')

for input_element in inputs:
    print(input_element.get("id"))
```

I got the following output with the code.

```
None
None
None
None
tc_kn
yu_kn
v_kn
kurumsalUnvan
ad_soyad
gsmAlan
gsmNo
evTelAlan
evTel
e_posta
kepAdresi
barkodNo
hesapNo
konu
image1
image2
image3
dosya3
dosya1
dosya2
guvenlik
```

Similarly, if you want to submit the form, you can do it through requests as well.

Comment: I can't interact with selenium any element on the site I share

Comment: I agree, I tried the same as well, that's because it takes too long to load the page that it times out before you can interact. That's why I used `requests`